# Interdependent includes in node.js result in a empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, include

I have two files that declare a class, both of them with `static` functions:

foo.js:

```
const bar = require('./bar');

console.log('bar in foo: ');
console.log(bar);

class foo {
  static _(test) {
    return 'foo_' + test + bar._(test);
  }

  static bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}

module.exports = foo;
```

bar.js:

```
const foo = require('./foo');

console.log('foo in bar:');
console.log(foo);

class bar {
  static _(test) {
    return foo.bar(test);
  }
}

module.exports = bar;
```

In VS Code, code completion work in both files to get the other file's static method.

But when I try to execute it:

```
const foo = require('./foo');
foo._('test');
```

I can see that the recursive `require` don't work as I thought it would:

```
foo in bar:
{}
bar in foo:
[Function: bar]
bar.js:8
        return foo.bar(test);
                   ^

TypeError: foo.bar is not a function
```

I know `class` in JS are syntaxic sugar around functions, but I am still surprised that the interpreter lose `static` members.

Can anybody explain the working of require in that case? And why it result in a empty object?

Comment: My best guess is that to be able to `require` foo, bar end up "mocking" it, but since foo do end up usable later, I'm still surprised it do not end up refreshing the reference in bar.